# Bypass Certificate expiration in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, ssl-certificate

I am trying to make a Https post request to an url having an expired certificate. Is there a way to bypass that security in Javascript? I was able to do it in C# and Java.

```
function post()
{
  var xmlhttp;
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xmlhttp.open("POST","https://something.com:8443/trigger",true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xmlhttp.send("code=6644&workflow.reponame=test");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this. Put simply: in someone else's browser, this isn't your decision to make.

Comment: I ended up contacting the person in charge of the site I was trying to connect to, they solve the certificate issue. It's a shame there's no way to do it like I did in C#.